# how to verify paypal payment in baasbox plugin

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, baasbox

I have setup baasbox and I already tested the paypal payments.  However I'm not able to implement the verify of payment from baasbox plugin.  Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: you'll need to be a little more specific than that. what have you tried so far that failed? show your implementation.

Comment: var result=Box.WS.post("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
                        {
                            params:{
                                'Accept':'application/json',
                                'Accept-Language':'en_US',
                                'ClientID':'Secret',
                                'grant_type':'client_credentials'
                            }
                        });
                        


    var body_returned=result.body;
    Box.log(body_returned);